# Error in installing setuptools (unorderable types: str() < NoneType())

Tags: python, setuptools

Python 3.4.2, 32 bit - Win 8.1, 64 bit

First I was trying to upgrade setuptools, but it was not successful. So I decided to uninstall the previous version. Now I can't install setuptools. I have tried the following:

1. pip install setuptools:

   ```
   Exception:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
       status = self.run(options, args)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 339, in run

       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 229, in prepare_
   files
       req_to_install.check_if_exists()
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 928, in chec
   k_if_exists
       self.satisfied_by = pkg_resources.get_distribution(self.req)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
   ne 461, in get_distribution
       dist = get_provider(dist)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
   ne 341, in get_provider
       return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
   ne 870, in require
       needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
   ne 740, in resolve
       env = Environment(self.entries)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
   ne 927, in __init__
       self.scan(search_path)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
   ne 957, in scan
       self.add(dist)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", li
   ne 977, in add
       dists.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('hashcmp'), reverse=True)
   TypeError: unorderable types: str() < NoneType()
   ```
2. Running `(Invoke-WebRequest https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py).Content | python -` in a powershell with admin privileges:

   ```
   PS C:\Windows\system32> > (Invoke-WebRequest https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py).Content | python -
   Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or
   Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again.
   At line:1 char:4
   + > (Invoke-WebRequest https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py).Content | python -
   +    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], NotSupportedException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletIEDomNotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
   ```

(I'm not willing to install Internet Explorer right now, but if you think I have to, then I will.)

3. Downloaded the [ez_setup.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py) and ran it:

   ```
   Installing Setuptools
   running install
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "setup.py", line 180, in <module>
       dist = setuptools.setup(**setup_params)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
       dist.run_commands()
     File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
       self.run_command(cmd)
     File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
       cmd_obj.run()
     File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7o_bqrd\setuptools-11.3.1\setuptools\c
   ommand\install.py", line 67, in run
       self.do_egg_install()
     File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7o_bqrd\setuptools-11.3.1\setuptools\c
   ommand\install.py", line 103, in do_egg_install
       cmd.ensure_finalized()  # finalize before bdist_egg munges install cmd
     File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
       self.finalize_options()
     File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7o_bqrd\setuptools-11.3.1\setuptools\c
   ommand\easy_install.py", line 319, in finalize_options
       self.index_url, search_path=self.shadow_path, hosts=hosts,
     File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7o_bqrd\setuptools-11.3.1\setuptools\p
   ackage_index.py", line 269, in __init__
       Environment.__init__(self,*args,**kw)
     File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7o_bqrd\setuptools-11.3.1\pkg_resource
   s\__init__.py", line 975, in __init__
       self.scan(search_path)
     File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7o_bqrd\setuptools-11.3.1\pkg_resource
   s\__init__.py", line 1005, in scan
       self.add(dist)
     File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo7o_bqrd\setuptools-11.3.1\pkg_resource
   s\__init__.py", line 1025, in add
       dists.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('hashcmp'), reverse=True)
   TypeError: unorderable types: str() < NoneType()
   Something went wrong during the installation.
   See the error message above.
   ```
4. Repairing python installation by running python-3.4.2.msi and choosing the repair option. But still no setuptools:

   ```
   >pip install scipy -U
   Collecting scipy from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/scipy/
   .0.tar.gz#md5=639112f077f0aeb6d80718dc5019dc7a
     Using cached scipy-0.15.0.tar.gz
     setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution
   ```

I think uninstalling and reinstalling python would fix the problem, but before trying that I thought maybe you can help me to find the cause of the problem and the right way to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Evidently that `ez_setup.py` file is for Python 2 where `'' < ()` is `True` i.e. not an error.

Comment: It was the file suggested [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows-simplified). Do you know where can I find the Python 3 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem (on Win 8.1 64bit, Python 3.4.2) with the change suggested here:

[https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/pull-request/122/ensure-py_version-and-platform-are-str-in/diff#chg-pkg_resources/**init**.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/pull-request/122/ensure-py_version-and-platform-are-str-in/diff#chg-pkg_resources/__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading `ez_setup.py`, use [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) instead. From the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html), if `setuptools` is not installed, it will install it first.

---

Since you're still getting an error, try installing [`pip`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip) and [`setuptools`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools) from Christoph Gohlke's Python Extension Packages for Windows repository. Make sure you download the 32-bit installers for Python 3.4. Once downloaded, run the `.exe` files and hopefully everything will be back to normal. There are tons of scientific computing packages there, so if you want [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) linked against Intel's MKL, and [`scipy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), which uses the enhanced version of numpy, go right ahead!

Answer (score 0):

Well it seemed to me that my python installation was completely messed up. It could have been related to a temporary installation of python 2 on my system a few weeks ago. Anyway, I thought it would be easier for me to just uninstall and reinstall the whole thing. So I uninstalled python and then reinstalled, but even that was not enough. Finally, I manually deleted `C:\Python34` and reinstalled python and now it works fine.