# Getting error while installing pocketsphinx package using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pocketsphinx

while i am trying to install

> pocketsphinx

package of python using pip in window 7 i am getting error like:

> typeerror: unorderable types Nonetype<> >= str<>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in installing setuptools (unorderable types: str() < NoneType())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894825/error-in-installing-setuptools-unorderable-types-str-nonetype)